# How to properly use a UIAlertAction handler in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller

Simply put, I would like to call a **method** or **reference a variable** from my class in a UIAlertAction handler.

Do I need to pass in a block to this handler or is there some other means to achieve this?

```
@interface OSAlertAllView ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *aString;
@end

@implementation OSAlertAllView

+ (void)alertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)msg cancelTitle:(NSString *)cancel inView:(UIViewController *)view
{
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancel style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
            // I'd like to reference a variable or method here
            weakSelf.aString = @"Apples"; // Not sure if this would be necessary
            self.aString = @"Apples"; // Member reference type 'struct objc_class *' is a pointer Error
            [self someMethod]; // No known class method Error
        }];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [view presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)someMethod {

}
```

Comment: Your `alertWithTitle...` method is a class method, not an instance method. Make it an instance method and you can do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `+` at the start of your `alertWithTitle...` method means it is a class method. When you call it, `self` will be the class `OSAlertAllView`, not an instance of type `OSAlertAllView`.

---

There are two ways you could change it to make it work.

Change the `+` at the start of the method to a `-` making it an instance method. Then you would call it on an instance instead of the class.

```
// Old Class Method Way
[OSAlertAllView alertWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" cancelTitle:@"Cancel" inView:viewController];

// New Instance Methods Way
OSAlertAllView *alert = [OSAlertAllView new];
[alert alertWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" cancelTitle:@"Cancel" inView:viewController];
```

The other way would be to create an instance to `OSAlertAllView` inside of you `alertWithTitle...` and replace the uses of self with that object.

```
+ (void)alertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)msg cancelTitle:(NSString *)cancel inView:(UIViewController *)view
{
    OSAlertAllView *alertAllView = [OSAlertAllView new];

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancel style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
            alertAllView.aString = @"Apples";
            [alertAllView someMethod];
        }];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [view presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```